# Does "Heart of the Alien" use the same game engine as "Another World"?

Tags: amiga, atari-st, game, sega

[Another World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_World_(video_game)) is a classical game originally for [Amiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga) and [Atari ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_ST) and subsequently reimplemented for many retro and modern platforms. As [described](https://fabiensanglard.net/another_world_polygons/) by Fabien Sanglard the game is implemented in bytecode and the engine is a bytecode interpreter. The game has a sequel named [Heart of the Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_the_Alien). It is released only for [Sega CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_CD) and no ports are known. This makes me think that the engine is completely different, despite the fact that the game visuals are very similar.

Does **Heart of the Alien** use a different engine than **Another World** and if so are there any attempts to be reimplemented using the engine of the original game?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an unofficial port to the Amiga, known as "Heart of the alien Redux". To my knowledge it uses the original engine with the data of the SegaCD version. No idea how much work there was required to make it actually work, but I presume that the Sega CD engine is not that much different from the Amiga engine.

http://www.indieretronews.com/2016/11/heart-of-alien-redux-amiga-v10-amazing.html

Comment: Actually, it has also a [port](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hota/) for modern platforms, but still no answer how similar it is to the original game.

Answer (score 5):

If the author's quote found on the Wiki page is accurate it seems the answer is "no", depending on various readings of the terms:

> neither the animations nor the game, entirely developed by Interplay,
> were up to the job

"Entirely developed by Interplay" can mean different things. If we take the statements at face value, it means "the game" is entirely new.

One *might* read "the game" to refer to the gameplay itself, ie, the map and game progression. In that case, he might be referring to what is essentially a new mission pack for the existing engine.

Given the change of platform, I think the former interpretation is more likely.